# Wires from exhaust

Tags: hyundai, exhaust, wiring, acceleration, elantra

Driving down the road today and i hear a snap, then lost all acceleration, these four wires wrapped in a casing were ripped out after wrapping around the axel, they are attached to part of the exhaust headed up into the engine, any ideas on what these wires are and where they go would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an O2 sensor wiring. No clue how it would have gotten tangled up into the drive shaft, or how it would have disabled the car like you describe.

Comment: It's still turning over but just won't catch